# Why is my furnace causing my electric bill to skyrocket?

Tags: hvac, furnace

I know it's the heat causing my electric bill to jump from $200ish to over $600 monthly. It runs almost constantly. It produces heat(astounding amounts) and blows it adequately. I don't think it's hooked up to the return.
Ive got a sneaking suspicion it's the limit switch.
Any thoughts? I can't afford to keep paying such exorbitant electric bills.

Comment: Thermostat fitted? Thermostat setting? Has someone turned it up?

Comment: Is it a gas furnace?

Comment: How do you know it's the furnace? Is it supposed to run almost constantly, or is that a problem?

Comment: What make and model is this furnace?

Comment: If it's producing "astounding amounts" of heat then TURN IT DOWN!  If you set the thermostat at 95F it's probably going to run constantly and it sounds like that's not what you want.

Comment: I had a large house that had similar bills when all electric heat, the next year I added a gas furnace , that cut cost in half. If I did not have gas available I would be looking at a heat pump. Electric or resistive heating is one of the most efficient ways to heat but it is also the most expensive. Other methods to reduce the bill may also include wood or pellet stoves. Some will also suggest turning the heat down this was not an option for me because of injuries cold causes pain. I had good insulation, so then double pane windows the bill went from +500 to 120-150$ with gas and windows.

Comment: It sounds like something changed, other than the weather? Others have posted good questions so I won't ask them again.   You said you "don't think it's hooked up to the return".  What do you mean by that?  There is no cold air return?  Is the furnace in conditioned space so it doesn't need a return.   More info could help us provide better answers.